# Why I cannot access via SSH to an EC2 instance through another EC2 instance without providing the .pem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, pem, openvpn

I need that all instances that I launch in a public subnet of a VPC can access via SSH without providing a `.pem`, just with its private IP. Additionally, I need to create an OpenVPN server in one of them so anyone that can access to the subnet via VPN can access to any instance via SSH without providing a `.pem` using its private IP too.

I do not know if this is possible, but if there is another way to do that I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you can access your instances without `.pem` file by using [AWS System Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/remotely-run-commands-ec2-instance-systems-manager/).

Use `Session Manager service of AWS System manager`  through the AWS console page.

[**Session Manager**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html): Users who want to connect to an instance with just one click from the browser or AWS CLI without having to provide SSH keys.

A user who wants to monitor and track instance access and activity, close down inbound ports on instances or enable connections to instances that do not have a public IP address.